# RuboCop Error - Define a global variable in Cucumber RUBY files

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, global-variables, cucumber, rubocop

I need to define a global variable in my Cucumber env.rb file which can be accessed throughout the framework in all step methods. Currently i am defining as this in my env.rb file:

```
$global_var ||= false
```

And i need to access this var into the Before hook as well After hook and few step methods where i am re-initializing this. It is working perfectly as i want. But the problem is, rubocop doesn't like this and throwing error as "do not use global variable". How can i resolve this ???

FYI, I tried using singleton to define this var as accessor and not quite sure where i am missing.

Comment: Sorry mate  - saw your query very late. was not awake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the config file for rubocop. use the link: 
[Example to Change](https://buildtoship.com/integrate-rubocop-in-your-workflow/)

Look for the passage starting with **When we look in the .rubocop_todo.yml file we see something like this:**  and also **Configure Rubocop to be your style guide**

Link to List of Configuration Changes possible:
[Link to List of Styles](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbatsov/rubocop/master/config/enabled.yml)

change .rubocop.yml file:

**Style To Change:**

`GlobalVars: Enabled: false`

Example File : [Example file - how it looks like](https://github.com/celluloid/culture/blob/master/rubocop/style.yml)

How to Configure Style: [Style/Inheritance Guide](https://github.com/celluloid/culture/tree/master/rubocop)